# Firebase email auth marked as dangerous

Tags: javascript, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

When some people try to log in to my Firebase website using firebase auth's sign in with email and Firebase auth UI, their browser says it is dangerous. The user who reported this has a verizon email and is using Safari. My Firebase app uses Https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that when you change the email layout in firebase, i shows the user a warning.

Comment: Do you have a way to fix that?

Comment: @awesomebanana2018 i set back all e-mail settings to default. As result all e-mails sent by firebase will also not get into spam folder. If you like to edit your e-mail style layout, you need to add a domain, which is explained [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). I think in that case your e-mails will also not receive a warning sign.